Failed to spawn: unable to find executable at 'my_binary'
i'm trying to bypass ssl using frida but when i execute frida-ps -U I only get the name of the application unless I add this argument to the command -a
When i execute one of the following commands:
frida --codeshare sowdust/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-2 -f
frida --codeshare pcipolloni/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-with-frida

I get this error Failed to spawn: unable to find executable at

Don't forget the -U option on the frida calls, otherwise frida will try to execute the process on your local Windows/Linux/MacOS system. When posting frida command-lines please do not truncate them. If you don't want to write the app [package] name then replace it by something like <app-name>.

@Robert oh yes i forgot to add it but now when i added -U the execution stays forever on [-] Waiting for the app to invoke SSLContext.init()...
